# Linkedin - REST API want to share network update using java 1.2 can't use scribe or other lib

Tags: java, rest, oauth, linkedin-api, scribe

we are trying to implement linkedin into our application and we want to use Rest API so we can share network updates via back-end using OAuth token to our own linkedin account

JavaScript API wont work for use because its token expires every 30 minutes and we have to login in every time (if more than 30 mins) to share network update. so we want to use REST API and OAUTH token to share network updates with java

we have considered Scribe and Spring Social (though spring social's linkedin module is still in release candidate as of now) but to use those library we need higher version of java and we are using java 1.2 right now with the application

is there a way we can still use the REST API and make OAuth calls to share network update or is there a Java library for OAuth that still supports java 1.2

Any help or direction would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no OAuth lib that works with the LinkedIn Api for java 1.2, in fact I'd argue that the only library that works well with all LinkedIn endpoints (because of some corner case encoding issues) is scribe.

Most of scribe code is 1.2 compatible. The only issues being some generics (`Map<T,U>`) and `@Override` annotations, which shouldn't be **that** hard to change.

If you're interested in digging the source and copy-pasting the bits you need (scribe is MIT licensed so you can do pretty much whatever you want with it), the **core** of the signature process is on [this class](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/scribe/oauth/OAuth10aServiceImpl.java).

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Pablo, if time permits will try to implement the changes and see if that will work for us, once again thank you for your time and help